# Не могу получить значение с помощью xpath

Tags: xpath

Есть вот такой кусок страницы:

```
<p>
  349
  <span>
    р.
  </span>
</p>
```

Как получить "349"?

Comment: А вы как то уже пытаетесь получить?

Comment: .//p[not(@id)][not(@class)][not(@style)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./p/text()[1]` если нужна первая текстовая нода

другой вариант

```
./p/node()[. instance of text()][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше бы видеть всю структуру разметки...
Если p - корневой элемент body, то `/html/body/p/text()`